# What are the advantage of using operational calculus for numerically solving pde compared to FE or FD?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis

For numerically solving a partial differential equation (PDE) what advantage does operational calculus (OC) has over common methods like finite difference (FD), and finite element (FE)?

I mean OC in the sense of Heaviside, as developped by Mikusinski.

I know that the choice between FE and FD, is a matter of taste, except if the PDE is of high order.
I couldn't find anyone sharing his impression on the usage of OC to solve PDEs.

Comment: Do you mean Operational Calculus in the sense of Heaviside? On the one hand, his methods have been superseded by Fourier and Laplace transform and distributional methods. But these are more analytical or theoretical methods, rather than numerical ones. So it's not clear what you mean by the numerical use of OP.

Comment: Do you mean by OC pseudodifferential operators ?

Comment: @user36539 No, I mean Heaviside (or Mikusinski) operational calculus.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Yes, I mean Heaviside approach. My understanding is that OC permits to convert a PDE into an algebraic problem. So, numerically, I wonder if there are instance where this makes sense. In constrast, FE and FDM are brute force methods in the sense that they directly rely on Taylor expansion theorem. For example, for the heat equation on a square, is it efficient to solve at each node an algebraic problem?

Comment: I think what you should investigate is the use of Fourier or Laplace integral transforms in numerical methods (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_methods). However, you should be aware that the application of these methods to a PDE on a grid gives you an algebraic system on the same grid. One has to also invoke the (fast) Fourier transform in an essential way as well.

Comment: For the use of the Laplace transform in particular, see "Numerical Inversion of the Laplace Transform", by Bellman, Kalaba, and Lockett.  Elsevier, 1966.  The instability of the inversion of the Laplace transform makes this very hard to apply in practice, and the idea never really caught on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion, the use of HOC (Heaviside Operationnal Calculus) is limited to equations with constant coefficients witch is a drastic restriction if one wants to analyse a physical phenomenon with great precison. In Oprationnal methods by Maslov a description of a special OC witch could be used to tract PDE with variable coefficients is presented and this approach is close to the use of Pseudodifferential Operators (in Hormander's sense). Note that in using this calculus the goal is to perform a qualitative analysis of the phenomenon described by the PDE rather that getting numeric values witch can be obtained by Finite Elements Methods  or Finire Difference Methods. I agree with Igor Khavine to cite spectral methods. there is also wavelets methods and their families (chirplets, etc) witch seam to be useful.